# How to convert datatype using Spring Mongo template

Tags: spring, mongotemplate

In Java I have the following Mongo temlate query which works fine:

```
query = new Query(where("department.departmentId").is(Integer.valueOf("31")));
```

since the department.departmentId field in the Mongo database is of type Integer.

Since this is just an example I want to be able to compare any field irrespective of its type with a String value (provided by a web client). So I don't want to use 'valueOf' constructions. I don't want to convert the value.

I tried:

```
query = new Query(where("department.departmentId").is("31").type(16);
query = new Query(where("department.departmentId").is("31").type(2);
query = new Query(where("department.departmentId").type(16).is("31");
query = new Query(where("department.departmentId").type(2).is("31");
```

Unfortunately nothing works. Is what I want possible?

Comment: Expand `nothing works`. Do you receive any exception?

Comment: what is type in your example?

Comment: The type is integer